# Titanium CloudPush Event Why does not work? (android)

Tags: android, mobile, notifications, titanium, push

I added push notification "events" but is not working.

I dont understand. Error can not be given and Log in is not working.

please help me. Thanks

my gcm module
    var gcm = require("nl.vanvianen.android.gcm");
        var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');

```
    /* If the app is started or resumed act on pending data saved when the notification was received */
    var lastData = gcm.getLastData();
    if (lastData) {
        Ti.API.info("Last notification received " + JSON.stringify(lastData));
        gcm.clearLastData();
    }

    gcm.registerPush({

        senderId : '480608162759',
        notificationSettings : {
            sound : 'mysound.mp3',
            smallIcon : 'notification_icon.png',
            largeIcon : 'appicon.png',
            vibrate : true
        },
        success : function(event) {
            Ti.API.info("Push registration success: " + JSON.stringify(event));

        },
        error : function(event) {
            Ti.API.info("Push registration error = " + JSON.stringify(event));
            alert(event.error);
        },

        callback : function(event) {
            Ti.API.info("Push callback = " + JSON.stringify(event));

            var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title : 'Push received',
                message : JSON.stringify(event.data)

                // buttonNames: ['View'],
                // cancel: 1

            });

            dialog.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                dialog.hide();
                if (event.index == 0) {
                    /* Do stuff to view the notification */
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        },
    });
       //Dont work eventlistener
    CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {
        console.log("Notification received: " + evt.payload);
    });
```

Comment: When you launch the application is the log of the registration giving you an output?

Comment: @maxdangelo Yes it is giving. But the event is not triggered. i dont understand why?

Comment: Before checking code, you should check if the setup of your notification provider is working (Certificates as example). What are you using for this?

Comment: @maxdangelo  Push notification is working but not working After a click from my push notifications. I use google android on the SenderID and GCM. Event is not triggered.

Comment: @maxdangelo i recruiting device token with this code and I can at the push notification. And then i add push notification event But if i clicking on the event push notification event doesn't trigger. And I don't understand where is the problem. I use senderId and gcm API key What can i do?